# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

Im working on a game and I want there to be a property of type Item (my own class) which starts off null and is set when the player picks up an item.
I have the code:

```
    useItem: Item;
```

declared at the top of the player class, and this in its constructor:

```
   this.useItem = null;
```

because unless there is an item, i want it to be null (this way i know nothing is there)

and in the Item class i have:

```
 init(holder: Player) {
        this.holder.useItem = this;
    }
```

which is called when the player picks up an item (which is already created earlier in the game)
but every time i run this code i get the error 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'useItem' of undefined

what can i do?

Comment: Have you read the error message text? What do you think it means?

Comment: A hint: you're not using the parameter passed are you?

Comment: I did read the text, but im curious if there is a way around this. In other languages i never had a problem becaues im just trying to assign a different object to the same name. what do you mean by the hint?

Comment: why do you think `this.holder` exists? Have you assigned it somewhere explicitly? "In other languages i never had a problem " --- in **any** other language it would be the same (or compilation error)

Comment: it means exactly what it states - the `this.holder` is `undefined`

Comment: I set it in the super's init method, forgot to call it :/ i feel dumb

Comment: but you probably want `init(holder: Player) { holder.useItem = this; }` (not `this.holder.useItem`)

Answer (score 3):

You try to reach the `useItem` member of `this.holder`, but `this.holder` was not initialized yet. Initialize `this.holder` before you try to use its `useItem` member.